# Azure Logic App - Update Blob API Connection through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps

I've searched online and browsed the available powershell cmdlets to try and find a solution for this problem but have been unsuccessful. Essentially, I have a few Data Factory pipelines that copy/archive incoming files and will use a web http post component that will invoke a Logic App that connects to a Blob container and will delete the incoming file. The issue I'm facing is that we have several automation runbooks that will rest Blob access keys every X days. When the Blob keys get reset the Logic App will fail whenever this happens because the connection is manually created in the designer itself and I can't specify a connection string that could pull from the Keyvault, as an example. Inside of the {Logic App > API Connections > Edit API Connection} we can manually update the connection string/key but obviously for an automated process we should be able to do this programmatically.

Is there a powershell cmdlet or other method I'm not seeing that would allow me to update/edit the API Connections that get created when using and Blob component inside a Logic App?

Any insights is appreciated!

Comment: You can edit connection api using ARM template, would it be acceptable for you ? Do you need any sample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've rotated your key in the storage account, you can use an ARM template to update your connection API. In this ARM template, the connection api is created referencing the storage account internally so you don't have to provide the key:

**azuredeploy.json** file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "azureBlobConnectionAPIName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the connection api to access the azure blob storage."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Storage Account Name."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "[parameters('azureBlobConnectionAPIName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('azureBlobConnectionAPIName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "accountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
          "accessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]"
        },
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/azureblob')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json** file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "azureBlobConnectionAPIName": {
      "value": "myblobConnectionApiName"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "value": "myStorageAccountName"
    }
  }
}
```

You can them execute the arm template like that:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <yourSubscriptionName>

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "ExampleDeployment" -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroupName" `
-TemplateFile "D:\Azure\Templates\azuredeploy.json" `
-TemplateParameterFile "D:\Azure\Templates\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
```

to get started with ARM template and powerhsell, you cam have a look at this article:

[Deploy resources with Resource Manager templates and Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy)